# How to calculate quantity based on a boolean field and retrieve values from a JSON field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, json, array, xampp

I'm working with a table called price_options that has the following fields: `id, slots, list_slots, and quantity`.

## Issue Description

---

My objective is to calculate the quantity for each price option based on the boolean value of the slots field. If slots is set to true, I need to retrieve the quantity from the list_slots field, which contains JSON data structured like this: `[{"start":"09:00","quantity":30},{"start":"09:30","quantity":30}]`. Otherwise, I should use the quantity field directly.

---

### 1- SQL For Creating Table:

```
CREATE TABLE price_options (
    id INT UNSIGNED PRIMARY KEY,
    slots BOOLEAN,
    quantity INT,
    list_slots TEXT NULL
);
```

### 2- Adding data in table for case: 1

```
INSERT INTO price_options (slots, quantity, list_slots)
VALUES (TRUE, 0, '[{"start":"09:00","quantity":30},{"start":"09:30","quantity":30}]');
```

### 3 -Adding data in table for case: 2

```
INSERT INTO price_options (slots, quantity, list_slots) VALUES (FALSE, 30, NULL);
```

---

## 4- Required Output for Both Cases:

### **Case 1:**

**slots** field is **true**, i want total quantity calculated from **list_slots** field.

```
Output should be (30+30) = 60
```

### **Case 2:**

**slots** field is **false**, i want total quantity from quantity field. This time we will ignore **list_slots** field.

```
Output should be: 30
```

---

### Note:

1. **list_slots** field type is text.
2. The MySQL version I'm using is **10.4.24-MariaDB** (Xampp).

---

I hope it helps to understand the issue
Any help or guidance on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) - provide sample data (#5) and desired output (#3).

Comment: I have edited my question. Can you please take a look now?

Comment: You have not read the article by the provided link. It describes in what form you'd provide sample data and desired output for it.

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm still unable to clarify the problem. I have read the article and I've provided the test case.

Comment: I see neither CREATE TABLE script nor INSERT INTO with sample data nor desired output for this data. You must provide these SQL scripts - this allows to reproduce your table and demonstrate/test needed SQL query.

Comment: I see, thank you for helping me out. Can you take a look now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146670/discussion-between-khuzema-and-akina).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE price_options (
    id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    slots BOOLEAN,
    quantity INT,
    list_slots TEXT NULL
);
INSERT INTO price_options (slots, quantity, list_slots)
VALUES (TRUE, 0, '[{"start":"09:00","quantity":30},{"start":"09:30","quantity":30}]');
INSERT INTO price_options (slots, quantity, list_slots) VALUES (FALSE, 30, NULL);
SELECT * FROM price_options;
```

| id | slots | quantity | list_slots |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | [{"start":"09:00","quantity":30},{"start":"09:30","quantity":30}] |
| 2 | 0 | 30 | *null* |

```
SELECT price_options.id, SUM(jsontable.quantity) quantity
FROM price_options,
     JSON_TABLE(list_slots,
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (quantity INT PATH '$.quantity')) jsontable
WHERE slots
GROUP BY 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, quantity
FROM price_options
WHERE NOT slots
```

| id | quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 60 |
| 2 | 30 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kzAWErGZ)

---

> The MySQL version I'm using is 10.4.24-MariaDB (Xampp).

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT id, list_slots, JSON_EXTRACT(list_slots, '$[0].quantity') quantity, 1 ordinality
  FROM price_options
  WHERE slots
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, list_slots, JSON_EXTRACT(list_slots, CONCAT('$[', ordinality, '].quantity')), ordinality + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE ordinality < JSON_LENGTH(list_slots)
)
SELECT id, SUM(quantity) quantity
FROM cte
GROUP BY 1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, quantity
FROM price_options
WHERE NOT slots
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W9DdO6Zq)

Comment: JSON_TABLE is not working in Mariadb v10.4.24. Any alternative of this?

Comment: @Khuzema This is **critical**, MySQL <> MariaDB. Answer updated.